# finite cylclic group, order of $(a,b)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite clyclic group. $a,b\in G$, find $|(a,b)|$ ($(a,b)$ is the group generated by $a$ and $b$).

Now what I did:

$n:=|G|,x:=|(a)|,y:=|(b)|,z:=|(a,b)|$

$(a)=\{0,n/x,..,(x-1)n/x\}$

$(b)=\{0,n/y,..,(y-1)n/x\}$

$v\in(a),w\in(b)\Rightarrow \exists c,d\in\mathbb Z: v+w=(cy+dx)/(yx)=(cy'+dx')*gcd(x,y)/(yx)=(cy'+dx')/lcm(x,y)$.

($x'=x/gcd(x,y), y'=y/gcd(x,y)$)

But cause of Benzot (or euclidean division) we can find $e,f\in\mathbb Z$ so that $(ey'+fx')=1$ so $z=lcm(a,b)$.

Now is there a quicker proof (one without calculation)?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\langle g \rangle  , a=g^k , b=g^m$. Then $\langle  a ,b \rangle=\langle g^{\gcd(k,m)} \rangle$. Proof: clearly if $a^sb^t=g^r$ then $r$ is a multiple of $\gcd(k,m)$. On the other hand if $r$ is a multiple of $\gcd(k,m)$ by euclidean division there is $s,t$ so that $ks+mt=r$ so $a^sb^t=g^r$